# How do you make an API request using browser fetch with token auth

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, access-token

I'm trying to make an API request using fetch(browser). A token is required in the headers to make the request.

I can make successful requests in node (server side).
However, when making requests on the browser, the `OPTIONS` request fails with 401.

```
const order_url = new URL(process.env.API_URL + 'orders/');
const params = { type: 'amazon', status: 'in_queue' };
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]));

const headers = {
    Authorization: 'Token ' + process.env.API_TOKEN,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};

fetch(order_url, {
  headers
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

The error i receive is `"NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."`
What would be the correct configuration for this to work on the browser?

Comment: Is this node environment?

Comment: Is the api CORS enabled?

Comment: This is the browser environment and CORS is enabled in the API.

Comment: @DuncanGichimu is this a bearer token? If so, you need the bearer header like so: `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + process.env.API_TOKEN,`

Comment: @kemicofa I've tried this in the  node environment and it works. I will restate my question.

Comment: @BenBeck It's not a Bearer token.

Comment: @DuncanGichimu `process` is something only accessible in node. Does process.env.API_TOKEN output the the correct token in the browser?

Comment: @kemicofa This is from a react app. Process is available. Nothing is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending headers properly.
Try this.

```
myHeaders = new Headers({
  'Authorization': 'Token ' + process.env.API_TOKEN,
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
});
```

and then

```
fetch(order_url, {
  headers: myHeaders,
  method: 'GET'
})
```

Comment: With this change, I get the same result - 401.